# $\lim\limits_{y \rightarrow 0}3y\int_{y^2}^{y}\frac{x^2\sin(x^2y^3)}{x^2+\cos(x^2y^3)}dx\quad x,y \in R$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

I would like to compute the following limit : 
$$\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow 0}{}g(y)=\lim\limits_{y \rightarrow 0}3y\int_{y^2}^{y}\frac{x^2\sin(x^2y^3)}{x^2+\cos(x^2y^3)}dx\quad x,y \in R, \quad \mid y \mid <1$$
My attempt : 
We can use this theorem : 
If $f :[a,b] \times I \rightarrow R$ is continuous ($I$ is open) and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ exists and is continuous, then , let $a<b$, then
$$g(y):=\int_{a}^{b}f(x,y)dx$$ is $C^1(I)$ and
$$g'(y):=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)dx$$
It means that $\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow 0}g(y)=g(0)$
So here, since $\mid y \mid <1$, we get 
$$\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow 0}{}g(y)= 0$$ ? I am not sure about that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $|y|<1.$ Then $y,y^2\in [-1,1].$ Thus the absolute value of the integral is bounded above by the length of $[-1,1]$ times the maximum of the integrand in absolute value over this interval. This is no more than

$$2\cdot \frac{1}{\cos 1}.$$

Thus the total expression has absolute value no more than $3|y|\cdot (2/\cos 1) \to 0.$

Comment: Ok this seams to be good, but, i don't understand how to you get such precision for $\frac{2}{\cos1}$.  The only thing i have is $\mid\frac{x^2\sin(x^2y^3)}{x^2+\cos(y^3x^2)}\mid \leq \frac{1}{1-(y^6x^4)}<1$ because near $0$ we have $\cos(h)>1-h^2$  ?

Comment: $y^3x^2$ lies in the interval $[-1,1],$ hence $\cos y^3x^2\ge \cos 1$ in this interval.

Answer (score 1):

By direct inspection the limit seems to be 0.

Set $$\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow 0}{}g(y)=\int_{y^2}^{y}\lim\limits_{y \rightarrow 0}\left[\frac{3yx^2\sin(x^2y^3)}{x^2+\cos(x^2y^3)}\right]dx\quad x,y \in R$$
which turns out to be
$$\int _{y^2}^{y}0dx=0$$
I could be wrong!!

Comment: I think that since $y$ is also in the integration limits it's not valid to simply flip the integral and limit.

Comment: Yes exact, but in this case I apply the theorem I wrote, and because $\mid y \mid <1$,then $y-y^2$ is not $(0)$, so... I don't really understand what are you trying to tell me here

Comment: Your theorem only applies when the limits of integration are constant.

Comment: Ok thank you $J_P$, so know I really don't know how to compute this limit...

Comment: @Dicordi Since $|y|<1$ then the condition on the integration limits $a<b$ in the theorem are not guaranteed; there will be cases when $a>b$ and the theorem does not clearly seem to accomodate that possibility.

Comment: Also since the limits of integration are changing when you take the derivative you need to take into account that as well.

Comment: The integral does not depend on the variable $y$ it depends on  $x$ only; $y$ is a constant.

Comment: Right, but when you take the derivative with respect to $y$ or when you're taking limits in $y$, you have to make sure to also include the $y$ in the limits. For example, when you put your limit inside the integral, the $y$ in the limits of the integral fell out of $\lim$ - this is kind of like saying $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x=x\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}1=x\cdot1=x$

Comment: You will only need that derivative of $y$ when you have $\int \frac{0}{0}dx$ or $\int \frac{\infty}{\infty}dx$ which don't seem to happen in this case.

Comment: OK yes I see, you didn't even use the derivative, the original question has something about derivatives. But still, because $y$ is in the integration limits, you can't just put $\lim$ inside the integral, that's a suspicious move, especially because $y$ ends up outside the limit even though it's the thing you're sending to $0$.

Comment: For example:
$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}\int_1^{e^y}\frac{1}{xy}dx=1
$$
But if we just put the limit inside the integral:
$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}\int_1^{e^y}\frac{1}{xy}dx=\int_1^{e^y}\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{xy}dx=\int_1^{e^y}0dx=0
$$

Comment: OK- I agree in this particular case because $y$ appears on one side of the limits. If $y$ appeared both in the lower and in the upper limit, you wouldn't have came to same result. As you compare the alternatives given so far in this case, all lead to the same conclusion.

Comment: Take instead
$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}\int_{1+1/y}^{e^y}\frac{1}{xy}dx
$$
and nothing changes.
All I'm saying is that your method employs limits questionably. I don't dispute that the result is correct, but that is irrelevant. $y$ can't still be around after you've taken the limit - all $y$'s have to be gone at that point, including the ones in the limits. In other words, the limits of the integral affect the behaviour of the integral and the limit can be sensitive to this.

Comment: I see your point. Although it makes a lot of sense, there are some holes to be addressed. For example, these new limits lead to $$\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}\tfrac{1}{y}\left[y-\ln(1+y)+\ln(y)\right]$$ which is still work by itself. Is it 1?

Comment: Yes it's $1$ because $\ln(1+y)-\ln(y)=\ln(1+1/y)$ and $1/y\rightarrow 0$ so we get $\ln(1+0)=0$

Comment: OK; you may be right!

Answer (score 0):

The function of two variables
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{3x^2y\sin(x^2y^3)}{x^2+\cos(x^2y^3)}
$$
is continuous at the origin $(0,0)$, so $|f(x,y)|<M$ for some constant $M$ in a neighbourhood of the origin. In the integral, $x$ runs from $y^2$ to $y$, so in particular, $|x|\leq|y|$. Then when $y$ is small enough, we have
$$
\left\vert\int_{y^2}^{y}f(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\right\vert\leq\int_{-|y|}^{|y|}|f(x,y)|\mathrm{d}x<\int_{-|y|}^{|y|}M\mathrm{d}x=2M|y|
$$
But $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}2M|y|=0$.

Comment: Why do you have the integral between $-\mid y\mid$ and  $\mid y \mid$ in the middle ?

Comment: Because $|y|\geq y,y^2\geq-|y|$ and so when you're integrating from $y^2$ to $y$ you get even more if you integrate from $-|y|$ to $|y|$ and the inequality is OK. I only did it that way because if $y$ is perhaps negative then $y<y^2$ and I don't want to bother distinguishing between cases.